# using the knockout js website tutorial - how to uppercase fullName (instead of just lastName)?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, updating

i'm just killing some time and getting my hands dirty with some knockout.js. I've never gone near it before, so I figured I'd take a look at what its all about.

On the official website - http://learn.knockoutjs.com,  I've modified the code on step 4/5 so that instead of the button turning the lastName value into uppercase when the button is clicked,  BOTH firstName and lastName are combined into variable called fullName and the view is updated to show fullName all in uppercase.

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here folks ? I'm simply trying to aggregate / concat the values for firstName and lastName and storing them in a var called currentVal which is assigned to value fullName in the view. When i click the button nothing really happens heh

This is my code (modified from the tutorial at step 4/5 , see if you can tell me where I might be doing something wrong here.

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);

  this.capitalizeLastName = function() {
    this.fullName = this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(); //with or without this line, it doesn't update fullName to uppercase :-|
    var currentVal = this.fullName();
    this.fullName(currentVal.toUpperCase());
  };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<p>Full Name: <input data-bind="value: fullName" /></p>
<p>Full Name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
<button data-bind="click: capitalizeLastName"> Go caps</button>
```

Comment: ah crap, sorry folks - it should read capitalizeFullName in the view,  and also the function should be named capitalizeFullName as well.  No idea why its not showing my updated code. Regardless, it will not work if i click the button ( when it reads capitalizeFullName, leading me to believe im doing something wrong here.

Comment: You don't have to add `\`\`\`\`` to each line. Paste your code -> select it -> Click on `{}` icon in the editor ([Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bb7H.gif)). Please read: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361) and [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you only need to update your `firstName` and  `lastName` variables, because `fullName` its a computed function that return those values, like so:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
  this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
  this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);

  this.capitalizeFullName = function() {
   this.lastName(this.lastName().toUpperCase());     
   this.firstName(this.firstName().toUpperCase());     
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<p>Full Name: <input data-bind="value: fullName" /></p>
<p>Full Name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
<button data-bind="click: capitalizeFullName"> Go caps</button>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks rcoro, I already succeeded in getting it to work this way - but what happens is, when we do it this way,  all the data-bind's for the static text and input text field values get UPPERCASED lol

What we're gunning for here rcoro, is the first four text and input fields to remain untouched and only the last two data-bind's on fullname to get UPPERCASED :-D

I'm going to try one last thing before adiga's solution/suggestion a shot, I think i've got it figured out now though.